# I cannot send the mobile barcode reader to the computer with TCP Server

Tags: java, android, zxing, tcpserver, android-ide

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barcodeLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(),result -> {
        try {
            if (result.getContents() != null) {
                String data=result.getContents();
                (new BarcodeSender(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(HOST_ADDR.getText()),3946)).execute(data);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BARCODE "+ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            statusText.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    });
```

I use ZXing package with Android/Java in Android Studio. I can read barcode data but cant send TCP Server.

BarcodeSender.java

```
public class BarcodeSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter printWriter;
    String adr;
    int port;
    Context context;
    public BarcodeSender(Context context, String Adress, int PORT) {
        this.adr = Adress;
        this.port = PORT;
        this.context=context;
        Toast.makeText(this.context, adr+":"+port, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String mess = voids[0];
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, mess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this.context, this.adr+":"+this.port, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Socket socket = new Socket(this.adr,this.port);
            DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DOS.writeUTF(mess);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exs) {
                Toast.makeText(this.context,"MSG_SENDER "+exs.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Toast messages cant showing because my app is shutdown.

Comment: Indeed. You cannot use Toast's in doInBackground. Better do it in onPostExecute.

Comment: But I cant send on pc TCP Server app is shutdown after scanning and showing barcode data